# Assigning first element of arraylist to another arraylist

Tags: java, javafx

How do I get the first element of an ArrayList from another class and assign it to another ArrayList?

```
public class PaymentScreenController {

    public ListView<Customer> lvCustomer1;
    public ArrayList<Customer> allcustomers;

    public ArrayList<Customer> cusarray;


    private Table tbl = new Table();

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        allcustomers = tbl.getCustomers();

        // Getting first element from 'allcustomers and assigning it to cusarray?
        // I have tried cusarray = allcustomers.get(0) but that doesn't work?









    }
}
```

And then assign cus array to a listview?

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: `cusarray = allcustomers.subList(0, 1)` <- Tried this already?

Comment: sublist isnt recognised?

Comment: please read an arbitrary tutorial on how-to use ListView (hint: _then assign cus array to a listview_ not directly, pay attention to the type of list that a ListView needs for its items)

Comment: .. and dont post uncompileable code snippest - instead provide a [mcve] that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
cusarray.add(allcustomers.get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the cusarray and add the item to the list:

```
cusarray = new ArrayList<>();
cusarray.add(allcustomers.get(0);
```

That should work for you.

Then for the ListView, I guess you'd want something like this:

```
lvCustomer1 = new ListView(FXCollections.observableArrayList(cusarray));
lvCustomer1.setCellFactory(param -> new ListCell<Customer>() {
@Override
protected void updateItem(Customer item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null || item.<function to get name>() == null) {
        setText(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.<function to get name>());
    }
}
});
```

Though I haven't tested the ListView bit.

EDIT: Now tested the code for the ListView and it works as intended.

Comment: _I haven't tested the ListView bit_ you should have :)